# How to receive SNMP MIB dump data?

Tags: linux, network-programming, snmp, net-snmp

I have a SNMP MIB dump from a device and would like request the (static) data via SNMP-Agent (net-snmp). The SNMP MIB dump looks like:

```
.1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = STRING: "xxx"
...
```

Where can I place the static SNMP MIB dump and how can I request the static values instead of a dynamic value, which are generate by the SNMP-agent? My SNMP-MIBs are located in `/usr/share/snmp/mibs/`.

Comment: Not sure I understand - You already have the SNMP response data given to you by the SNMP agent. And now you want to run the agent again with this data as an input, and to receive the value of a specific given OID for example?

Comment: Yes, i will place the MIB dump on my computer and request the data via snmp-agent. But it seems like its not possible without changing the snmp-agent source code.

Comment: I think `grep <oid> <MIB response data>` and then some `awk` manipulation will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

The NET-SNMP Agent is not designed this way. So you can not just load some data into it. You'll have to use so called SNMP Simulators that allow you to load and use any MIB files and your own data including snmpwalk dumps. The good example of such tool is **NetDecision Smart Agent** (http://www.netmechanica.com/products/?prod_id=1019). It allows you to load MIB dumps produced by net-snmp commands like snmpwalk (Import data option).
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i decide to use snmpsim http://snmpsim.sourceforge.net/snapshotting.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what a "SNMP Simulator" does, and much more. The good ones can change data dynamically, run many agents simultaneously, create simulations in many ways including importing from 3rd party walkfile, etc. Since Andrew posted a link to his product, we post a link to ours [http://www.gambitcomm.com/](http://www.gambitcomm.com) 
and a pretty picture

[image]